# How to implement selection and crossover in using genetic algorithm to find square root of a number in C

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to find out square root of a float number using genetic algorithm. 
I have initialized population of random numbers and a fitness function. How do I implement selection of parents from population and uniform crossover?

Comment: are you checking if the squares of parents are closer to the number you're trying to find the square root of ?

Comment: I'm figuring out how to select parents ? Those who have highest fitness values ?

Comment: higher fitness = higher probability to get selected.

Comment: It depends on your fitness function... Which one are you using?

Comment: natural implementation would be `num - (candidate * candidate)` where you search for the minimal value.

Comment: @giladhoch you mean abs(that) ?

Comment: For selection, use whatever you want, the problem is simple enough to avoid overengineering there. Simple pick two random chromosomes will do. As for crossover, which chromosome coding scheme are you using? Also you didn't mention mutation. Without it the algorithm won't converge past the capabilities of initial population.

Answer (score 2):

**SELECTION** 
The function given by gilad (the one you are using) seems fine. Why not just follow a standard procedure ? You can find some ideas on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_%28genetic_algorithm%29)

**CROSSOVER** 
If you are considering a candidate as a 32 bit vector (31 actually), then doing a uniform crossover consist in choosing bits of either parent with half probability.

The idea will be :

- Toss a coin
- If head take on parent one,
- If tails take on parent two

Programmatically an efficient way of creating a child from 2 parents will be to generate a random 32 bit number `r`, and given parents `a` and `b` do :

```
 child = (r & a) | (~r & b);
```

Comment: Hm, I would probably have gone with `|` rather than `+`, if I am bit-fiddling, I want to be as clear as possible (and while bit-wise or and addition produces the same result in this specific case, bit-wise or is a bit clearer).

Comment: In C++ "~" is used for bitwise complement, not sure for C. "!", a logical negation might give wrong result, 0 for non zero int.